# How to convert llvm profraw to cobertura

Tags: cmake, clang

I need to switch a cmake based project from g++ to clang for some reasons. I've made the switch to llvm-11 on Ubuntu 20.04. I got the project itself compile, unit tests work as well. Though, getting coverage reporting working again seems tough.

I need to create a cobertura xml file in order to integrate it into the existing CI/CD infrastructure (Jenkins and Gitlab). I've been using an older version of [1] for cmake cobertura reporting.

I thought 'llvm-cov gcov' should do the trick for me already to do the switch, but I just end up with an empty xml file with no error reported.

Next to the empty xml there is a new default.profraw file generated by llvm-cov that ends up in the build directory. I got so far as to figure out that the .profdata file format which llvm-profdata can convert to seems to be more promising as intermediate format for conversion than the raw data format. So I've generated a .profdata file for testing from that using:

```
llvm-profdata-11 merge -sparse default.profraw -o default.profdata
```

And I can generate an HTML file from this as well which actually contains expected coverage:

```
llvm-cov show my-unit-tests -instr-profile=default.profdata ../src/*.cpp -path-equivalence -use-color --format html > coverage.html
```

Here is also the related snippet from the CMake file:

```
append_coverage_compiler_flags()

setup_target_for_coverage_gcovr_xml(
        NAME coveragereports
        EXECUTABLE my-unit-tests
        DEPENDENCIES my-unit-tests  my-app-lib-testing
    #BASE_DIRECTORY "coverage"
    #BASE_DIRECTORY "../" 
    EXCLUDE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/*" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test/*" "/Library/*"
)
```

What tools / options do I have to convert the coverage data generated by clang(11) to cobertura xml?

[1] https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake

Comment: Could you please clarify for me the following questions: 1) What do you mean by older version of [1]? 2) Do you have the exact commit-hash for said version?

Answer (score 0):

[`llvm-cov`](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html#id11) could produce a report in `lcov` format that could be easily converted to Cobertura. Use something like [lcov-cobertura](https://pypi.org/project/lcov-cobertura/) Python module or anythong else.